# Java Format output String from RAF

Tags: java, string, format, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to output data from RAF in a text area GUI. I am getting output (title is different length, but 35 char max), but all attempts to put String into columns fails.

This is what I currently have:

```
while (count < noItems) {

    String title = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
        title += raf.readChar();
    }

    int noCopies = raf.readInt();
    double price = raf.readDouble();


   result+=String.format("%-40s", title);
   result+=(noCopies+"\t "+ twoDigit.format(price)+"\n"); 
    count++;
}
mainTextArea.setText(result);
```

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Fixed formatting.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're exceeding **maximum length of string** (2^31 - 1) as you are adding all columns in one string `result` (thus all attempts to put String into columns fails). Try to add every columns in JTextArea(`mainTextArea`) every time in `while` loop . Try this code,

```
while (count < noItems) {

String title = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    title += raf.readChar();
}

int noCopies = raf.readInt();
double price = raf.readDouble();


result = String.format("%-40s", title) + (noCopies+"\t "+ twoDigit.format(price)+"\n"); 
mainTextArea.setText(result);
count++;

}
```